# Как задать стиль функции alert()

Tags: javascript, css

Как задать стиль функции alert().
Если можно то задать id или class что бы прописать стили в css.

Comment: Если вы хотите придать стили для всплывающего окна, то его вам нужно создать, а не пробовать давать стили alert(), что конечно же бессмысленно... Вот пример по созданию: http://sergey-oganesyan.ru/javascript-s-primerami/kak-sdelat-vsplyvayushee-okno.html

Answer (score 5):

`alert` - это часть браузера, а не DOM сущность, её нельзя изменять.
Обязательно нашлись бы мошенники, которые что-нибудь гадкое придумали как тогда с окном ухода с сайта.

Answer (score 0):

Ты не можешь изменять стиль стиль стандартного `alert`, но можешь создать кастомный `alert`, то есть тот, который ты сделал сам.

### Пример кастомного `alert`

```js
function CustomAlert() {
  this.render = function(dialog) {
    var winW = window.innerWidth;
    var winH = window.innerHeight;
    var dialogoverlay = document.getElementById('dialogoverlay');
    var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialogbox');
    dialogoverlay.style.display = "block";
    dialogoverlay.style.height = winH + "px";
    dialogbox.style.left = (winW / 2) - (550 * .5) + "px";
    dialogbox.style.top = "100px";
    dialogbox.style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('dialogboxhead').innerHTML = "Заголовок";
    document.getElementById('dialogboxbody').innerHTML = dialog;
    document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot').innerHTML = '<button onclick="Alert.ok()">OK</button>';
  }
  this.ok = function() {
    document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";
  }
}
var Alert = new CustomAlert();
```

```css
#dialogoverlay {
  display: none;
  opacity: .8;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

#dialogbox {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 7px;
  width: 550px;
  z-index: 10;
}

#dialogbox>div {
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 8px;
}

#dialogbox>div>#dialogboxhead {
  background: #666;
  font-size: 19px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #CCC;
}

#dialogbox>div>#dialogboxbody {
  background: #333;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #FFF;
}

#dialogbox>div>#dialogboxfoot {
  background: #666;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="dialogoverlay"></div>
<div id="dialogbox">
  <div>
    <div id="dialogboxhead"></div>
    <div id="dialogboxbody"></div>
    <div id="dialogboxfoot"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="alert('Стандартный alert')">Стандартный alert</button>
<button onclick="Alert.render('Кастомный alert #1')">Кастомный alert #1</button>
<button onclick="Alert.render('Кастомный alert #2')">Кастомный alert #2</button>
```

Comment: Это обычные модальные окна, а `alert` - индикация работы именно браузера :) Но годно, конечно.

Comment: @Other ну да, так и есть, а другого варианта в данном случае просто нет)

Comment: "индикация работы именно браузера"? Что это?

Comment: Коренное отличие нативного alert от всего, что можно сделать самому в том, что он синхронный (также вызывает фокус своей вкладки, но это уже не везде).